# passing data through text box from select option into another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to pass data through a text box which is selected through the 'other' in select option. However, when I run the program, the data is not passed. Any ideas how to resolve this?  here is the code that I am using. I have added most of the code below. I have to pass information through the select option in the form of a text box. However the information is not passed. Is there any other method that can do this, passing through text to another page?

```
 <?php include_once("header.php"); ?>

<?php

$q_sel = "select * from tbl_drug";
$r_sel = mysql_query($q_sel);
?>

 <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
            $('#my_textarea').hide();
$('#Quantity').change(function()
    {
        var o = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        console.log(o);
        if(o=='other') $('#my_textarea').show(); else $('#my_textarea').hide();
});
            });
        </script>
    </head>
<body style="background-color: #25383c;background-image: url(img/background.png);">
      <?php include_once("nav.php"); ?>

        <h1>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Medication Appropriateness Index</h1>
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
             <div class="col-sm-12">
             <div class="well">
             <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="save_drug.php" method="post">
             <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Drug:</label>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                  <select name="drug" id="Drug" class="form-control" required="">
                          <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Please select A drug...</option>
                          <?php
                          while($r1 = mysql_fetch_array($r_sel))
                          { ?>
                          <option value="<?php echo $r1['d_id']; ?>"><?php echo $r1['drug_name']; ?></option>
                          <?php
                          }
                         ?>

                  </select>
                  </div>
             </div>
              <script>
$(function() {
    $("#dose").tooltip();
});
</script>

        <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Route:</label>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                  <select id="Quantity" name="quantity" class="form-control" required="">
                          <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Please select A dosage...</option>
                          <option value="PO">PO</option>
                          <option value="IV">IV</option>
                          <option value="PR">PR</option>
                          <option value="Topically">Topically</option>
                          <option value="other">Other (please specify)</option>
                    </select>
                      <textarea name="my_textarea" id="my_textarea"></textarea>
                    </div>
                 </div>





             <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                  <input type="hidden" name="patient_id" value="<?php echo $_GET['patient_id']; ?>">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                  </div>
             </div>
             </form>

             </div>
             </div>
         </div>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

always use 'name' attribute for inputs , because only name can send data on submit.

```
<textarea name="my_textarea" id="my_textarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: thank you, but when I added the 'name' the data is still not passed through. Am I missing something else?

Comment: how are u passing data ? Submit button ? ajax ?

Comment: submit button                                                                                                                                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                  <input type="hidden" name="patient_id" value="<?php echo $_GET['patient_id']; ?>">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                  </div>
             </div>

Comment: I am very new to this so please be patient!

Comment: so i guess for the type submit , you must have a <form> to be submitted. which i cant see in your question. kindly edit the question and post all of the code there.

Comment: I have added the code, sorry it is so much, thanks for the help

Comment: so , tell me any of the data is not being posted or, just some of it ?

Comment: I have other data that is being passed through another input text, and select option, also, the data from the option in the code is being passed, but not the text part.

Comment: not getting much ideas here.. i think data should pass..
well, how are you checking whether data has passed to save_drug.php or not. i mean how are you confirming it ?

Comment: if I remove the text box section data is passed no problem, in fact if I select the options above 'other' it passes. I am not sure because all of the other areas pass through ok.